# Unable to load xml file in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

[image: load xml file]I am using TestNG for WebDriver.

I have created my custom XML file to run methods.
But unable to load xml file in eclipse under TestNG.

How i can upload new xml in eclipse for TestNG?

testng.xml is present on desktop but disabled.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How i can upload new xml in eclipse for TestNG?

Comment: See, wasn't that hard. ;o)

Comment: But xml file is disabled, you can see in attached screen shot.

Please tell me how i upload my own written xml in TestNg.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are trying to run your testng.xml, but if you are, paste your xml file into your java project, click right button / Run As  / TestNG Suite